# R: Missed values when scraping webpage

Tags: html, r, dataframe, web-scraping, missing-data

When scraping data from a webpage, some elements/values are not returned.

Specifically, I use the rvest package to scrap.

The webpage that contains the information I want is https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/ - however, when I scrap the data, the columns with prices only return "$-".

Sample code:

```
library(rvest)

webpage <- read_html("https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/")
tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")

tbls_ls <- webpage %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[1:(length(tbls)-2)] %>%
  html_table()
```

Output of first df:

```
> List of 22  $ :'data.frame':  7 obs. of  6 variables:   ..$ Instance   
> : chr [1:7] "B1L" "B1S" "B2S" "B1MS" ...   ..$ Cores                  
> : int [1:7] 1 1 2 1 2 4 8   ..$ RAM                                   
> : chr [1:7] "0.50 GiB" "1.00 GiB" "4.00 GiB" "2.00 GiB" ...   ..$
> Temporary Storage                            : chr [1:7] "1 GiB" "2
> GiB" "8 GiB" "4 GiB" ...   ..$ Price                                  
> : chr [1:7] "$-" "$-" "$-" "$-" ...   ..$ Prices with Azure Hybrid
> Benefit1 (% savings): chr [1:7] "$-" "$-" "$-" "$-" ...
```

What can I do to get the whole value of these specific elements?

Answer (score 0):

They have a single set of price data irrespective of the filter. So you need to take that attribute's value and parse the json.

```
library(rvest)

webpage <- read_html("https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/")
tbls <- html_nodes(webpage, "table")

webpage %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[1:(length(tbls)-2)] %>%
  html_table()


ss <- webpage %>% html_nodes("table span.price-data ") %>% xml_attr('data-amount') 

lapply(ss,function(x){data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(x))})
```

Sample output:

```
[[176]]
  regional.asia.pacific.southeast regional.australia.east regional.canada.central regional.canada.east
1                           1.496                   1.496                   1.376                1.376
  regional.europe.west regional.japan.east regional.united.kingdom.south regional.us.east.2 regional.usgov.virginia
1                1.488               1.464                         1.448              1.373                   1.504
  regional.us.west regional.us.west.2
1            1.376              1.248

[[177]]
  regional.asia.pacific.southeast regional.australia.east regional.canada.central regional.canada.east
1                           4.464                   4.464                   4.224                4.224
  regional.europe.west regional.japan.east regional.united.kingdom.south regional.us.east.2 regional.usgov.virginia
1                4.448                 4.4                         4.368              4.365                    4.48
  regional.us.west regional.us.west.2
1            4.224              3.968
```

You need to match that particular value and take the price from this.

Comment: Thank you - it worked like a charm. However, could you maybe share the intuition? I can't seem to detect that there was a json file, where do you see that?

Comment: No, There's no json file, it's just json data, if you see the scraped data for price - you'd see nested data with braces and :, very much of key-value pair, which resembled json structure.

Comment: Ah, now I see it. What if I want a column for each price scenario for each region? That is, PriceScenarioA.RegionX, PriceScenarioA.RegionY, PriceScenarioB.RegionX, PriceScenarioB.RegionY sort of thing?